# Calling stored procedures with an OUT parameter not work?

Tags: mysql

Dear community: I have created a procedure in `mySQL`：

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if EXISTS GetCustomerLevel $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomerLevel(
      in  p_customerNumber int(11), 
     out p_customerLevel  varchar(10)
 )
 BEGIN
   IF p_customerNumber > 50000 THEN
     SET p_customerLevel = 'PLATINUM';
   ELSEIF (p_customerNumber <= 50000 AND p_customerNumber >= 10000) THEN
     SET p_customerLevel = 'GOLD';
   ELSEIF p_customerNumber < 10000 THEN
     SET p_customerLevel = 'SILVER';
   END IF;     
 END$$
```

the php as：

```
  header("Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");  
  $dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=class";

  $customerNumber = 103;
try {
    $conn  =new PDO($dsn,'root','root',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    // execute the stored procedure
    $sql = 'CALL GetCustomerLevel(:id,@level)';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $customerNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    // execute the second query to get customer's level
    $r = $conn->query("SELECT @level AS level")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($r) {
        echo sprintf('Customer #%d is %s', $customerNumber, $r['level']);
    }
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

but the result as:

Customer #103 is
there is no

```
    $r['level'];
thx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be able to successfully use your procedure like this (*skipping opening a connection and error handling for brevity*)

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare("CALL GetCustomerLevel(:id, @level)");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $customerNumber));

$stmt = $con->query("SELECT @level level");
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt = null;

echo "Customer #$customerNumber is {$row['level']}";
```

Output:

```
Customer #103 is SILVER
```

---

But it would be **much cleaner and easier** for you if you use a `FUNCTION` rather then a `PROCEDURE`

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GetCustomerLevel(_number INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8)
RETURN CASE WHEN _number > 50000 THEN 'PLATINUM'
            WHEN _number BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000 THEN 'GOLD'
            WHEN _number < 10000 THEN 'SILVER' END;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31502/1)** demo

And then use it like this

```php
$dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=class";
$customerNumber = 103;

try {
    $con = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'password');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT GetCustomerLevel(:id) level");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $customerNumber));

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt = null;

    echo "Customer #$customerNumber is {$row['level']}";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exeption: " . $e->getMessage(); 
}
$con = null;
```

Output is still the same:

```
Customer #103 is SILVER
```

Comment: Dear：THX.  BUT it still show : 【Customer #103 is】 ;then I use print_r($row); ,the result as：  Array ( [level] => )

Comment: I use your FUNC GetCustomerLevel，but result also:【Customer #103 is】

Comment: Dear peterm：
Thx for your help.

I find I use wrong dbname for dsn.
   It's ok when I change.

Thx for you help!

Comment: Dear peterm： sorry， if i want to use in/out put procedure for php，How to code it?

Comment: Dear  peterm：I had check the hook on your answer alerady.